# Pound symbol added to URL in ios 14

Tags: swift, url, base64, ios14

I have a running app in a webserver, that redirects to an app installed on a iOS 14 device.
the url is in the form of

`myapp://?p=someBase64EncodedString`

and the application is decoding the string.
after upgrading to iOS 14, the url the app gets is

`myapp://?p=someBase64EncodedString#`
and the pound symbol added to the end of the string fails to decode on my device.
When using `ignoreUnknownCharacters` everything works fine, but where did this `#` come from?

Comment: How is the app decoding the url? A `#` is perfectly valid in a URL and indicates the start of the fragment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691495/how-to-load-nsurl-which-contains-hash-fragment-with-uiwebview

Comment: Can you post the full url? (including the `someBase64EncodedString`)

Answer (score 2):

As @jtbandes mentioned in the comments, `#` is valid character in a URL.

To avoid this kind of issues, the safest way to parse a URL is by using [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents), following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218047/6791677) answer.

Here is an example:

```
let urlString = "https://test.host.com:8080/Test/Path?test_parameter=test_value#test-fragment"
let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString)

print("scheme: \(urlComponents?.scheme ?? "nil")")
print("host: \(urlComponents?.host ?? "nil")")
print("port: \(urlComponents?.port ?? -1)")
print("path: \(urlComponents?.path ?? "nil")")
print("query: \(urlComponents?.query ?? "nil")")
print("queryItems: \(urlComponents?.queryItems ?? [])")
print("fragment: \(urlComponents?.fragment ?? "nil")")
```

This will have as output:

> ```
> scheme: https
> host: test.host.com
> port: 8080
> path: /Test/Path
> query: test_parameter=test_value
> queryItems: [test_parameter=test_value]
> fragment: test-fragment
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Could Swift 5 and raw strings be the culprit? My guess is that the application is using # as a custom string delimiter and on the decoding is replacing some special character with an #.

Comment: I had a similar problem. See here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/126/whats-new-in-swift-5-0 and also https://ericasadun.com/2018/12/26/swift-5-gives-us-nice-things-custom-string-delimiters/

Answer (score 0):

It may be an api action in a redirect for an api you used. If so, it is out of your control and potentially scope of access.